# how to set the "expires after" date on an email outlook 2010

Tags: email, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2010 and would like to set that 'Expires after' property found in the 'Delivery options' section in the 'Properties' dialog.

Turns out that 'ExpiryTime' and 'RetentionExpirationDate' don't actually set that date anymore (if it ever did).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I'm getting it to work now.
_s shows up as '7/29/2013' and z displays as '8/5/2013'.  This makes the Expired Time show up as '8/5/2013 12:00 AM'.

```
typelib Outlook {00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 9.4
str foldername="Temp"
Outlook.Application app._getactive
Outlook.MailItem msg=app.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1); err out "no selection"; ret
Outlook.MAPIFolder froot=app.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.Item(1)
Outlook.MAPIFolder fdest=froot.Folders.Item(foldername)

_s.timeformat("{D}")
DATE z=_s
z=z+7
msg.UnRead = 0
msg.ExpiryTime=z
```